# How do I see all my data that has been read in Cloud Firestore?

Tags: android, database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have successfully read all my user data into cloud firestore but unable to see all my data in one go.

As you can see in the screen capture, "Sara" has been read. Beforehand, "Mira" and "Kiena" has also been read.

[image]

How do I see "Mira" and "Kiena" together with "Sara" in one screen? I want to see all the data that has been read in Cloud Firestore.

I need to have all this as a record for my thesis.

I set the user data with this code:

```
private DocumentReference mDocRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().document("sampleData/userdata");
```

Comment: I'm not really clear what you're asking.  What you show here is a database with a single collection, which has a single document, which has a single field called "name".  And that's it.  It's not clear to me what your are expecting to see otherwise.

Comment: What's shown in your sceenshot is the Firestore Console which shows the information contained in the database. It has nothing to do with reading or writing. That being said you can use the console to review the contents (as shown) or even add new data but that functionality is limited. Note that you do not have any data in your Firestore related to Mira and Kiena so you cannot see it. If that data existed, it would be shown in the console.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add this

```
SetOptions.merge()
```

inside the set function in your code

what is happening now is that firestore takes a key = name and values = sara/mira/etc and keeps overriding the values since the key is the same, but when you use the merge options it will not override and will display all in a list

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're setting the user data with something like:

```
db.collection("sampleData").document("userData").set(...)
```

Any time you execute this code, you're overwriting whatever data already exists in `userData`.

---

If you want to create a new document each time you run the code, do:

```
db.collection("sampleData").add(...)
```

This will generate a new document with a unique ID each time you execute it.

---

If the document needs to be associated with the current user from Firebase Authentication, you'll want to use the user's UID as the document name. That'd look like this:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
db.collection("sampleData").document(uid).set(...)
```

Comment: private DocumentReference mDocRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().document("sampleData/userdata"); I'm setting the userdata like this. How do I implement this code to do as your code above? @Frank van Puffelen

Comment: You'd replace that with one of the code snippets from my answer. There really isn't much more I can say about it. Did you try one of them? What was the result?